# How do i enable all displays on Ubuntu running NVIDIA with multiple GPU and multiple Destkop

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, display

I recently moved from windows to ubuntu as my main os and I have some trouble activating all displays and using all GPUs; I have 4 displays with 2 gpu (currently) on this system and I wondered how I turn them all on in the world?

I can see 2x displays attached to a single GPU, but the other GPU is completely ignored by the pc.

- Prajwal

My X11 config.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "SLI" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: take a look at `xrandr`

Comment: i am good with linux as a server but when it comes to using it as a desktop i am extremely new so can u help me a bit more here.

Do i have to turn on SLI or multi GPU?

Comment: `xrandr` is a tool that will allow to enable/disable, rotate, move, etc. monitors. I don't know how you'd use it for your situation, but try running that command, check out the man pages about it. It may be able to do what you want.